# kde 'window shortcuts' are temporary

Tags: linux, hotkeys, kde-plasma

I'm running the KDE desktop, and I'd like to associate hotkeys with a set of windows and use those hotkeys to activate those windows from anywhere.  Ideally, this would work like in Windows - where the key launches the app the first time you press it, and thereafter just brings it to the front.  But I don't think that's possible in KDE (why not???).

Anyway, the kwin window menu has a "More Actions/Window Shortcut" option that does let you set a key combination that will bring that window to the front.  Except that it only works for the current session.  Is there no way to make that association permanent?

In my normal Windows workspace, I have 2 PuTty sessions logged on to a unix host under different user ids.  Each of these has an associated hotkey. In addition, I have the app I work in (a browser of sorts) with its own hotkey, and a programming editor with its own key.  I am constantly switching between these 4 windows, and I do it all with keystrokes.  And I use the same keystrokes to start those sessions up when I first need them.  It's great - the only Windows feature that I seriously miss when running Linux.  How can I come closest to having that in KDE?  Or some other Linux desktop?

Comment: I have found some references to an 'xdotool windowactivate...' command that does something similar, and I guess that can be embedded in a shell script and then associated with a hotkey.  But seriously...  If Kwin has its own "Window Shortcut" option, why can't they make that automate the process better than having to write a clumsy script to do the same thing...?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried xdotool, and combined in a script and attached to a KDE custom shortcut, it actually works.  Launches the app if xdotool doesn't find it, and activates the window if it does.  Painful, but it does work.  The app in question is WIN32 code - hence launching it via wine.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=`xdotool search --name Medialine`
if [ "$pid" == "" ]; then
        wine /home/rob/wem.exe&
else
        xdotool windowactivate $pid
fi
```

Comment: Yes, another tool I would like to suggest is `wmctrl`. You can easily change your script to accept arguments (windowname, application to launch) so you only need one script for multiple keybindings/apps.